# How to empty out elements of two arrays after merging two arrays together

Tags: python, arrays, merge

```
#FUNCTION
def merge_array(a, b):

    c = []

    for i in a:
        c.append(i)

    for z in b:
        if z not in c:
            c.append(z)

    c.sort()

    return c

#MAIN
a = [1,5,2,8,9]
b = [8,4,2,8,10,3,14]

print("Array 1: {}".format(a))
print("Array 2: {}".format(b))
print("Merged List: {}".format(merge_array(a, b)))

print("Array 1 empty: {}".format(a))
print("Array 2 empty: {}".format(b))
```

tried putting a.pop() and b.pop() in for loops but does not completely erase the elements and changes 'c'

Answer (score 0):

You can do just like this:

```
>>> c = set()
>>> while len(a)>0:
...  c.add(a.pop())
...
>>> while len(b)>0:
...  c.add(b.pop())
...
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[]
>>> c
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 14])
>>> x = list(c)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 14]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it would help but i need to actually append it to the empty list c = []

Comment: This doesn't handle duplicates like the original code does. His sample de-dupes.

Comment: wait me for a moment

Comment: thanks for the help but I can't use sets and such but I was able to modify my code using the while loops

Comment: you can merge a and b the same, and remove duplicated elements on your own without `set`  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if that is what you are looking for but if you just want to add the lists together and take care of duplicates try:

```
list(set(a+b))
```

Answer (score 0):

`pop` works depending on how you do it. It sounds like you were iterating from the front and popping off the back. Another way is to clear the arrays using list comprehensions when you are done. Your example doesn't get rid of repeats in `a` but does get rid of them in `b`. If you want no repeats at all, there is a shorter example in the comments but I kept your original algorithm in tact.

```
def merge_array(a, b):
    # if you only want unique values from each you could
    # c = set(a + b)
    #
    # ... but following your recipe
    c = a[:]
    for z in b:
        if z not in c:
            c.append(z)

    # in either case, this clears the originals
    del a[:]
    del b[:]
    return sorted(c)

#MAIN
a = [1,5,2,8,9]
b = [8,4,2,8,10,3,14]

print("Array 1: {}".format(a))
print("Array 2: {}".format(b))
print("Merged List: {}".format(merge_array(a, b)))

print("Array 1 empty: {}".format(a))
print("Array 2 empty: {}".format(b))
```